# Pegar um único registro para colunas iguais

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho um exemplo de tabela:

```
produto    |   supermercado
----------------------------
    1      |        1
    4      |        2
    6      |        1
    5      |        1
    8      |        2
    7      |        3
```

Eu quero pegar todos supermercados existentes nessa tabela, sem pegar números repetidos. O resultado seria:

```
 supermercado
----------------
      1
      2
      3
```

Desconsiderando os supermercados repetidos. Não consegui nem começar com uma `query`, pois não sei como fazer para retirar esses resultados iguais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para retirar os resultados iguais é só usar o comando `DISTINCT` na query.

Assim ele não retorna valores repetidos, ficaria ssim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carrinhos.supermercado FROM carrinhos
```

Comment: select distinct campo from tabela where condição

Answer (score 1):

Use a palavra "distinct" na sua query sql, ele tem a função exatamente de eliminar valores repetidos na query:

```
select distinct supermercado from tabela
```

Answer (score 0):

pra fazer o DISTINCT de uma unica coluna usa DISTINCT ON.

```
select distinct on (ed.id) ed.id, ed.nome from eventodisparo ed
```